# Create GUI (dialog) in Visual C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, window

I want to create a menu of this style: When I click in Iniciar, the main code of the project should run.

[image]

That is, when Iniciar is clicked, this window should be closed and a new one with the main code should open. How do I do this in Visual c++?

My main problem is to know which type of archive should I use to generate this kind of window and how to configure my project so when I run it, the first window to show is this one.

Thank you, Alex.

Comment: I don't have much experience with C++'s gui dev, I hope others would answer your question accordingly. If I may make an off-topic suggestion I would say you should consider qt. You will have your button up and running in 10 mins.

Comment: FYI this would generally not be called a "menu".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry for my bad English? What should this be called in order to edit my post.

Comment: Dunno... "dialog" maybe? There aren't enough conventional cues in the image to really tell what form of GUI element this is intended to be. Strictly speaking. Like, conceivably this could even be a "splash screen".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What I need is something of this style: min 4:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiOOWDb4YjE&nohtml5=False

So when PushButton is clicked, the window is closed and the main program opens

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just as simple as when you click that button, this window closes and a new one opens showing what the main code does.

Comment: Okay the comment just said "What I" when I saw it before :P You're describing the mechanism very well, but without more conventions in the window's design it's hard to know how to categorise it. Maybe stick with "dialog" for now then. But it could also be a "launcher", "splash screen", or a few other things depending on various aspects of the behaviour of the window itself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't exactly know how to call it if it finally works the way I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a listener on the buttons click event.

This is done with something like this:

```
//Set up the callback
button->Click += new EventHandler(this, OnClick);

//This is called when the button is clicked
void OnClick(Object *Sender, EventArgs *Args)
{
    // Your code goes here
}
```

This article explains it pretty well: http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/controls/button.htm

hope it helps